# Подскажите способ реализации клиент-серверного приложения

Tags: android, сервер, клиент

По моему тз приложение на андройде(клиент) должно ожидать, пока на сервере(хочу на php написать, так как я его немного знаю) не появится "сообщение". У меня есть такой вариант: раз в N секунд посылать get запрос на сервер(отправляя логин+пароль) и обрабатывать ответ. Но будет большая нагрузка и на клиент и на сервер. Что же делать?

Comment: `TCP / IP`. Почитайте про сокетные соединения. P.S - сам не юзал

Comment: Отправлять пуши с сервера на клиент при наступлении событий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Socket - постоянное соединение с сервером.
К сожалению, на php я так и не смог реализовать вебсокет.Очень легко сделать на .Net'е. Там есть SignalR.

Ваш вариант сильно будет грузить сервер, на сокете сервер сам говорит клиенту, что есть новая информация.
Если интересно - могу кинуть линк на чат, который делал(.net)

Comment: Спасибо, за думаю, это то, что я искал. Не мог бы ты подсказать, возможно, есть более простое решение задачи

Comment: Можно токинг использовать, заместь логина и пароля.Смотри, если будет аудитория где то 50 человек, то еще можна будет делать запросами, я собственно в .net asp mvc девелопер, но мобайлом тоже сейчас интересуюсь, и говорю с точки зрения сервера. А на чем пишеш приложение?

Comment: Андроид приложение я буду писать на java. А вот насчёт серверной части уже передумал, думаю писать на python

Comment: Пока не знаю что сказать, поскольку сам сейчас думаю про такое...